# Key not valid for use in specified state errror when getting private key

Tags: wcf, cryptography, rsa

I have a **wcf service hosted by a windows service**. We encrypt passwords using **private certificates** encrypted by RSA algorithm. The certificate (**pfx** file) is installed on the server when logged in remotely as the user A. The application throws an exception "**Key not valid for use in specified state**" when it tries to get the private key. The windows service runs under the account local system. When in the assembly calling the decrypt function it runs under account A (impersonation is used on the different calls in the wcf service). The server is a 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2. The same code works for decryption in other applications installed on Windows Server 2012 servers.

I've already done the following, but end up with same error message:

1. Installed the certificate once more (uninstalled certificate in certmgr.msc, removed keyset in Crypto folder, checked that I get a different error message (keyset not available), restarted server,  reinstalled same certificate, restarted server).
2. Deleted Crypto folder, reinstalled certificate.
3. I've trusted the certificate system-wide (refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/370217/trust-ssl-certificate-to-local-system-account)
4. I've changed the user the windows service runs under to be account A.
   I've checked that the user A has access to the private key using this command: winhttpcertcfg -l -c CURRENT_USER\MY MyCertificate.
5. The string to be decrypted has the same length as used in the other applications where we don't have this problem, so we don't think it has something to do with the length (The string length is 137). In addition we know specifically that it fails on getting the private key. (Refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx(fOAEP is set to false)
6. I'v created a new certificate with a different name on the server logged in remotely as the user A.
7. I've checked that the domain, assembly and mscorlib is fully trusted

Need expert help! I can use the old encryption withouth certificate but that is not as secure. And it is so frustrating to have used this much time on it without any results...

Best regards, Kristine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself by creating a small application that only did the specific thing that my code in the wcf service was failing on. Everytime it was working I added some more complexity. This way I figured out that the wcf service had to run as the user A mentioned above. In addition I figured out that it would work without some requirements I had for impersonation on the WCFService. For every service method I had this attribute:
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]. I still use impersonation from the applications calling this WCFService (since the WCF Service is in domain X and the application calling it is in domain Y), but it works when I removed the attributes.

Kristine:)